# What is BusyBox?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, c, busybox, python3

Just wondering what BusyBox is used for and if I can use it for my project.

I have seen the Philips Hue Bridge runs BusyBox and I would like to use it on a relatively small, but powerful controller, maybe a Pi4?

Comment: _What’s the difference in BusyBox compared to just plain Linux_ - your question is unclear, Busybox is not Linux alternative and there is not such thing as _plain_ Linux

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk there you go, updated if it wasn’t clear.

Comment: https://busybox.net/about.html https://busybox.net/FAQ.html#whatis

Answer (score 2):

[BusyBox](https://busybox.net/about.html) is a single executable optimized for minimal size that is a shell with small but functional versions of most of the critical system commands built into it.

The intent is to provide as much critical functionality of a unix command line environment as possible in a minimal size for embedded systems.  BusyBox lacks full compatibility and functionality of the original commands in favor of a small executable.

Many embedded systems use busybox combined with a linux kernel and application specific vendor executables, where the user interface is fully implemented by the vendor executables, but busy box is available to run scripts to initialize the system and run background scripts needed by the application.